# graphicx includegraphics globally centered

Tags: graphics, horizontal-alignment

Is it possible to globally set `\includegraphics` pictures to be centered horizontally on page?

I have read the manual and see some unfamiliar global settings keys: `\setkeys{Gin}{width=0.75\textwidth}`

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that your margins are symmetric on the page.  If not, say so.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[showframe,pass]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\centerline{\includegraphics[width=.3\textwidth]{example-image}}

\centerline{\includegraphics[width=1.1\textwidth]{example-image}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I was hopeing for a preamble to put in my style file bus as David Carlistle lined out rhere is no such option...

Answer (score 1):

`\includegraphics` in common with most similar LaTeX constructs such as `\parbox`, `tabular` etc, is not a display construct it is just an inline box, so positioned like a big letter, it has no mechanism to control its position. You center a graphic in the same way as you would center a word, place it in the scope of `\centering` or `\begin{center}...\end{center}`

Comment: Thanks for that explaination. I have issues with pandoc converter to word and had to delete all \center to get passed...

Comment: @novski you should never use `\center` that is the internal implementation of `\begin{center}` always use the environment form  or use `\centering`

Comment: im sorry i misslead this comment as it was \centering that led to errors in  pandoc conversion.